# Host name showing (none) at login

Tags: linux, hostname

I am a newbie to Linux environment and building a Linux system from scratch using busy box. I created */etc/hosts* and */etc/hostname* file. But every time I start the system it shows (none)login:
But I can change the hostname using hostname command after logging in. I don't want any FQDN hostname or dynamic hostname configuration from DNS server. The content of the host name files are:-

$cat /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   tiny
```

$cat /etc/hostname

```
tiny
```

Is there wrong with the procedure or file. Please any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your machine both 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.1.1 or did you make a typo?  See my answer for how to combine the entries on one line and per-OS steps.

Comment: I copied the configuration from a working ubuntu system and it goes like this:-

`127.0.0.1   localhost`
`127.0.1.1    satchit.xyz satchit`

It was like this since installation.

Comment: switch it to the one line layout that i suggested in my answer with: `127.0.0.1 localhost tiny`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're likely going about this the right way and just need to either restart the system `sudo reboot` (or just `reboot` as the root user) or reload networking.

On Ubuntu and other Debian-variants, you're correct - you need to update `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts`.  To reload networking: `service networking reload` or `invoke-rc.d networking force-reload`.

On Fedora/CentOS and other Red Hat variants, you can set the hostname using the `hostnamectl` program.  To reload networking: `/etc/init.d/network reload`

On Android, I believe the command you want is: `setprop net.hostname <your name here>`.

Also, you can combine your entry in `/etc/hostname` to:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost tiny
```

Comment: Solved it..Since its a minimal system. Had to add default hostname setup in the init script. Also it doesn't have any interface configuration yet.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` doesn't work for my embedded arm Linux box. Instead, I put this line in the start script:

```
echo tiny > /proc/sys/kernel/hostname
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your IP-address is not really 127.0.1.1 (it seems unlikely).

On most Linux systems, you have the [ifconfig](http://www.tecmint.com/ifconfig-command-examples/) tool, which can show your IP-address.  I would check if the IPv4 address displayed by ifconfig matches the IP-address given for "tiny" in your /etc/hosts file - and modify it to match.  Once you have done that, you should be able to ping "tiny" to verify that the hosts file is updated.  Verifying that the hostname is going to be *used* takes a reboot, of course.